# Can we set/edit the loading animation/label time of the web browser?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, jquery, browser

The question looks weird, but I would like the explain with every details to make it clear.

I have a web page that I'm working on it. When you click the 'Show' button , It gets some data records from database and show them in the same page but in the different form. (it hides existing form and shows another form)

When I browse my page on Chrome: (version 28.0.15)

I go to my page. Then click 'show' button. After I click the button,

it shows lttle animation which turns around itself next to the browser tab which means 'loading'

Here is the screenshot for Chrome:

[image]

Then it keeps showing that 'loading animation' until proper form is completely loaded.
Then it shows the proper form on the page and stops the 'loading' animation.

When I do same thing on firefox(version 22.0) , everything is same as chrome. Works normal.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

It shows 'Connecting' label until proper form is completely loaded.
Then it shows the proper form on the page and stops showing 'Connecting' label on tab.

HOWEVER;

When I do same thing on Internet Explorer (version 10)

It shows 'waiting/loading' label for couple seconds.

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

After couple seconds, it is just shown as the page has been loaded. After a minute or minute and a half, it loads the data records and show the proper form.

This makes the user think that button is not working and keep clicking button. Actually its working. Getting results takes around a minute from database, but since Internet Explorer 10 does NOT show that it is still loading, then user thinks its not working.

After detail information ( I hope its clear enough) , my question is:

Is there anything that I can do for this issue? or Can I set this 'loading/waiting' label's time?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this browser, and create your own loading function.  You could try http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/, or just add a generic, spinning wheel loading if you don't know the progress amount.

Comment: Maybe you should consider lowering that interval of 1 minute. It's huge!

Comment: @machineaddict : it has already been lowered actually :) I can't go lower than a minute for now. Thanks though

Comment: If this is not in import of a huge file, you should consider lowering it again. I never delivered a user interface loading for more than a 2 seconds (and 2 seconds it's too big). Caching your queries might just do it. Please explain a bit more about what actually a user is entering in the form and what result should expect from database.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is [piecon](https://github.com/lipka/piecon), this plugin shows your favicon as a progress pie chart.